# need an idea for message showing

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, locationlistener

can anybody suggest me what should i implement, to show a wait message untill LocationListener.onLocationChanged get called ?
I tried using a dialog without title, but the problem is-
1. If i make it `setCancelable(false)`, than user is unable even to press back button.
2. If i make `setCancelable(true)`, then it goes out before onLocationChanged().
below is my code

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Please Wait for GPS Signals...").setCancelable(false);
mLocationWaitDialog = builder.create();
mLocationWaitDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParam = mLocationWaitDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();

layoutParam.y = -height / 2; // y position
mLocationWaitDialog.show();
```

Comment: you can use ProgressDialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this:

In the OnCreate method:

```
if (lastKnownLocation == null) {
        Log.i("Location", "lastKnownLocation es null");
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Buscando...", "");
}
```

dialog is declared above, its a ProgressDialog.

Then, in a Handler:

```
handler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Log.i("Location", "Mensaje recibido2");
            if(dialog!=null){

            dialog.dismiss();
            }

            LatLng gpsrc = new LatLng(msg.getData().getDouble("lat"),
                    msg.getData().getDouble("lon"));

            continuar(gpsrc);
        }
    };
```

My onLocationChanged method:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    double nuevalat=location.getLatitude();
    double nuevalon=location.getLongitude();
    origen=new LatLng(nuevalat, nuevalon);
    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    bundle.putDouble("lat", origen.latitude);
    bundle.putDouble("lon", origen.longitude);
    Message mescoords = new Message();
    mescoords.setData(bundle);

    try {
        handler.sendMessage(mescoords);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

This way, when the onLocationChanged method is called, a message is sent, which dismiss the ProgressDialog. Try if with ProgressDialog the user can back, Im not sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(activity);
pd.setMessage("Loading.. Please wait");
pd.show();
```

inside onLocationChanged() stop it

```
pd.dismiss();
```

Comment: i tried it, not working, having same proble, i am unable to do anything on that activity.

Answer (score 0):

I would try setting a timeout timer that sets cancelable to true after a certain amount of time.  That would solve your problem of having it go away right away, while also not locking the user in a loop if no GPS can be found.

Comment: but in that case, till the time cancelable is false, i'll be unable to do anything on activity.